# EntityFramework using navigation property to populate computed property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api

Basically what I want to do is return a read only string (user name) which is dependent on the navigation property User and just concatenates the first and last name together.

Ideally I'd just assign a value to OwnerUserId and then use the navigation property to retrieve the data if this is possible? I want to keep the model class as clean as possible.

Any ideas?

**POCO Model**

```
namespace Model
{
public class TicketReply
    {

    public int TicketReplyId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    /* ....more.... */

    /* User ID FK */
    public int OwnerUserId { get; set; }
    /* User Navigation property */
    [ForeignKey("OwnerUserId")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public User User { get; set; }

    /* Here is where I am stuck.... */
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return User.FirstName + " " + User.LastName; }
        set { }
    }

    }
}
```

****DB initialiser**** - just to give some context

```
private List<TicketReply> AddReplies(DbContext context)
{
        var replies = new List<TicketReply>
        {
            new TicketReply { TicketReplyId = 1, TicketId = 1, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, OwnerUserId = 1, Text = "My initial query"},
            new TicketReply { TicketReplyId = 2, TicketId = 1, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, OwnerUserId = 2, Text = "Test reply."},
            new TicketReply { TicketReplyId = 3, TicketId = 2, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now, OwnerUserId = 1, Text = "Test query"} 
        };
        replies.ForEach(status => context.TicketReplies.Add(status));
        context.SaveChanges();
        return replies;
}
```

Thanks
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Roughly (and typing from memory)
Make it part of the `User`, e.g...

```
public class User
{
    [NotMapped] // or from code  "modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(x => x.UserName);"
    public string UserName
    // your user name implementation
}
```

> You cannot just assign OwnerUserId and expect it to work - User will
>   be loaded when you load Ticket.   Also you don't use 'OwnerUserId' in
>   your fk-entity - to search for for User.

You can use that to 'set' the User 'it points to' - it's saved when you first do the 'SaveChanges'.

e.g...

```
var user = new User {First = ... Second=...};
db.Tickets.Add(new Ticket{ User = user, ...});
// or...
db.Tickets.Add(new Ticket{ OwnerUserId = ownerid, ...}); // to point to exisitng one you know exists         
db.SaveChanges();
...sometime later on...
var ticket = new Ticket { OwnerUserId = ownerid };
// ticket.User is null - won't work
var ticket = // tickets query // db.Tickets.Where(x => x.TicketId == ticketid).FirstOrDefault();
var username = ticket.User.UserName; // now it works, you have your User loaded
```

Or explicitely...

```
var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == ownerid).FirstOrDefault();
var username = user.UserName;
```